# How to setup ssl certificate to azure cloud service?

Tags: azure

I have a cloud service(and linux vm inside)
with mysite.cloudapp.net domain.
i need to install ssl certificate for this vm
how can i do that?
Thanks,
Yosi

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate-portal/

Comment: Did you check the portal? Documentation? Did you encounter a problem?

Comment: i dont understand it, i dont have web role
i have a vm inside cloud service
am i wrong?

Comment: Setup your custom domain so requests get to your VM and then just setup the certificate on the VM accordingly with the web server there.

Comment: I bought a domain, bought ssl certificate, uploaded the certificate to the cloud service by the portal, and it is not working.
What am i missing?

Comment: @ShiranDror 
I don't know how to make step 2?
Can i make it from the portal?

Comment: any help? i have no idea